# DropzoneJS & Laravel - Output form validation errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I am trying to output form validation errors when you hover over the "X" in the dropped off file in Dropzone.

What I get:

[image]

How can I make the `object Object` output the actual error message from the form validation? I can alert the error message but can't actually show the error message upon hovering over the x.

My js file:

```
 Dropzone.options.fileupload = {
    maxFilesize: 20,

    init: function () {
        thisDropzone = this;
        this.on("error", function (file, responseText) {

                $.each(responseText, function (index, value) {
                    alert( value); //this shows the alert of the error message

                });


        });
    }
};
```

My controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'max:20000',
    ]);
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution, look at stackoverflow.com/a/66603779/5723524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue.

To anyone who might have the same issue.

I fixed it by simply putting `$('.dz-error-message').text(value);`

Full code:

```
Dropzone.options.fileupload = {
maxFilesize: 50,
init: function () {
    thisDropzone = this;
    this.on("error", function (file, responseText) {
        $.each(responseText, function (index, value) {
            $('.dz-error-message').text(value);
        });
    });
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just laravel validation errors use that.

```
...
        init: function () {
            thisDropzone = this;
            this.on("error", function (file, responseText) {
                $.each(responseText, function (index, value) {
                    if (index === 'errors'){
                        $('.dz-error-message').text(value.file);
                    }
                });
            });
        },
...
```

Or if you just want dropzone.js error outputs change.

```
if(index === message)
```